# missing column in my final output causing an error, how to: retain the column or skip the error using lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

My `lapply` function cannot continue because of an error. What I noticed is because the column with `which.max` are gone in the column when there is no data for it, therefore `lapply` do not continue. If I am not explaining it well, here's the data and script:

data:

| store | fruit | color | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nina | banana | yellow | 1 | 9 |
| Lana | apple | red | 2 | 3 |
| Nina | grapes | green | 4 | 2 |
| Nina | banana | green | 4 | 7 |
| Lana | banana | yellow | 3 | 6 |
| Lana | apple | green | 2 | 5 |
| Lana | grapes | purple | 3 | 4 |
| Nina | grapes | purple | 2 | 3 |

and the script:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

list = c("apple", "banana", "mango", "grapes")
data=read_tsv("/home/polen/Desktop/data.tsv", col_names = TRUE)

group_func <- function(list) {
  df <- data %>% filter(fruit == {{list}}) %>%
    group_by(fruit) %>%
    summarise(color = names(which.max(table(color))), min_start = min(start), max_end = max(end)) %>% select(fruit,color,min_start)
  assign(list, df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

lapply(list, group_func)
```

this will return two files: apple and banana and an error "*Column `color` doesn't exist.*"
However, if I remove the `select` function:

```
list = c("apple", "banana", "mango", "grapes")
data=read_tsv("/home/polen/Desktop/data.tsv", col_names = TRUE)

group_func <- function(list) {
  df <- data %>% filter(fruit == {{list}}) %>%
    group_by(fruit) %>%
    summarise(color = names(which.max(table(color))), min_start = min(start), max_end = max(end))
  assign(list, df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

lapply(list, group_func)
```

it will return 4 files: apple, banana, mango and grapes. Mango having only 3 variables (which causes the error in lapply).

What I want is to either:

1. skip the error so it will continue to the next loop.
2. retain the column that was removed in summarise so the loop will continue.

I tried tryCatch but I am not able to make it work, especially since (although not included in my above script), I am exporting those files to my computer. Although maybe it will work, I'm just really noob about it.

I will really appreciate help for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

First of all, the reason a try catch doesn't work is as follows:

- When it gets to mango, there are no rows, so `color = character(0)` (empty character vector). If you run your code `names(which.max(table(color)))` where `color = character(0)`, the output would be `NULL`.
- Setting the column `color` NULL would essentially drop the column, hence `color` not existing when you do the select (try running `data.frame(color = NULL)` for example and you will see that the result has no columns)

### Direct solution

To solve for this directly, we could check if your code is `NULL` and replace with `NA` so that the column isn't dropped. For example, we can define a function as follows to do this check:

```
get_max_val <- function(x){
  result = names(which.max(table(x)))
  if (is.null(result)){
    return (NA)
  } else{
    return (result) 
  }
}
```

Now, if you re-define your grouping function as such, it will work:

```
group_func <- function(list) {
  df <- data %>% filter(fruit == {{list}}) %>%
    group_by(fruit) %>%
    summarise(color = get_max_val(color), min_start = min(start), max_end = max(end))
  assign(list, df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

### Alternate proposal

Seeing the output of the above function, you can re-think the problem as such:

1. Read in your data (using the sample you provided; note that your second column was not called fruit in your table so I renamed manually)

   ```
   library(dplyr)

   data = read.table(text = "store  fruit   color   start   end
   Nina banana  yellow  1   9
   Lana apple   red 2   3
   Nina grapes  green   4   2
   Nina banana  green   4   7
   Lana banana  yellow  3   6
   Lana apple   green   2   5
   Lana grapes  purple  3   4
   Nina grapes  purple  2   3", header = T)
   ```
2. Group by `fruit` and `color`. Then count the number of colors, the minimum start and the maximum end

   ```
   data %>%
     group_by(fruit, color) %>%
     summarise(color_count = n(), min_start = min(start), max_end = max(end))
   ```

   Output is

   ```
     fruit  color  color_count min_start max_end
     <chr>  <chr>        <int>     <int>   <int>
   1 apple  green            1         2       5
   2 apple  red              1         2       3
   3 banana green            1         4       7
   4 banana yellow           2         1       9
   5 grapes green            1         4       2
   6 grapes purple           2         2       4
   ```
3. Notice that for each `fruit`, we have counts of `color` so if we arrange in descending order by `color_count` and take the first row, we will keep the fruit with the highest `color_count`. Let's do that now and also compute also the min start and max end

   ```
   result = data %>%
     group_by(fruit, color) %>%
     summarise(color_count = n(), min_start = min(start), max_end = max(end)) %>%
     arrange(fruit, desc(color_count)) %>%
      group_by(fruit) %>%
      summarise(top_color = first(color), min_start = min(min_start), max_end = max(max_end))

   result
   ```

Resulting output is:

```
  fruit  top_color min_start max_end
  <chr>  <chr>         <int>   <int>
1 apple  green             2       5
2 banana yellow            1       9
3 grapes purple            2       4
```

If you did want to assign to the global env once done, you can do:

```
list_of_fruits = c("apple", "banana", "mango", "grapes")

lapply(list_of_fruits, function(fruit_name){
    filtered_result = result %>% filter(names == {{fruit_name}})
    assign(fruit_name, filtered_result, envir = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much and especially the detailed explanations!